# How to find and remove the string from string using ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to find & remove a string from string. See the examples below,

**Input1**:

> a = 'mangalore'

**Input2**

> b = 'mc'

**Outputs**

**b** values should not present in **a** for output1 `#angalore`

**a** values should not present in **b** for output2 `#c`

**Solutions:** converting string a,b to array then doing a-b & b-a

it will give results. How to implement using string in ruby.

Helps appreciated!

Comment: There is already a solution to this problem in your question. What is actually your question?

Comment: I think they're asking how to perform the subtraction without converting to an array first

Comment: yes. without array i need to give the solutions.

Comment: _"i need to give the solutions"_ – sounds as if you are supposed to find the solution yourself.

Comment: yes, i want the result in better way. now got it

Comment: When asked for a clarification of the question, please edit the question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions are intended to stand on their own. That is, readers should not to be expected to read all the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem, along with relevant input and expected output data, and any errors you're receiving. Without those it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
main > 'mangalore'.tr 'mc', '#'
#⇒ "#angalore"
main > 'mc'.tr 'mangalore', '#'
#⇒ "#c"
```

Comment: Why not `delete` ?

Comment: @steenslag because I have carefully read the OP requirements.

Comment: I must be missing something.

Comment: @steenslag _“[...] for output1 `#angalore`”_ :) the code above produces the output requested.